# 'Application': is not a class or namespace name

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, c++-cli, crypto++, managed-c++

I'm trying to utilize Cryptopp AES Library on C++ Form App. by using the Visual Studio 2015 with Update 2.

The thing is that I have to use "No common Runtime Support". However when I do this, It gives me some errors, like:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2653   'Application': is not a class or namespace name SON c:\Users\Win\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SON\SON\MyForm.cpp   18  

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2871   'Data': a namespace with this name does not exist   SON c:\users\win\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\son\son\MyForm.h 9   

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2871   'Drawing': a namespace with this name does not exist    SON c:\users\win\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\son\son\MyForm.h 10  

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C3861   'EnableVisualStyles': identifier not found  SON c:\Users\Win\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SON\SON\MyForm.cpp   18
```

But, when I build the code with Common Language Runtime Support, it doesn't give any error, but this time I couldn't create a UI for Form App.

Here are my CPP code, I didn't make any changes on it

```
#include "MyForm.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

#include "C:\Users\Win\Desktop\cryptopp562\osrng.h"
using CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool;



[STAThread]
void Main(array<std::string^>^ args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is `MyForm.h` being included twice? `#include`-guards should be preventing that from causing problems, but I would still fix that anyways if I were you.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer,I deleted one, but nothing has been changed

Comment: Anyone to answer ??

Comment: The question cannot be answered without knowing the definition of MyForm.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change `MyForm form` to `[Application name]::MyForm form`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).